# How to make adaptive image is larger than the container in the bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, css, background

I want to create an adaptive image that is larger than the cells in the bootstrap 4 alpha 2. Use as a background - it is impossible, it's clipped. So wrote the code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 container-circle">
<img src="img/background-areapeople-circle.png" id="backgroung-circle">
<section>
    <div class="text-uppercase">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    <aside class="text-uppercase"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></aside>
</section>
```

With styles for image:

```
#backgroung-circle{
    position: absolute;
    left: -12rem;
    top: 0;
    width: 150%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

But when the screen is the scale of more than 120%, it is too large cutting pictures, then a section with the text goes beyond the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to these:

- Use 'container-fluid' as a main container
- [Remove gutter](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know) between cells
- Add additional [media queries](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/media-queries-responsive-web-design/) to set parameters for some specific screen size

Hope it works